# Why is juice from concentrate cheaper?

Tags: beverages

Distilling the concentrate from juice and then adding water again seems an energy intensive process. If the supply chain is long this might make sense, but even in Florida orange juice from concentrate is cheaper - and apple juice is routinely made from concentrate, even in the regions where apples grow abundantly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about price determination, not cooking

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic, but for what it's worth, I think your question is actually "why is fresh juice expensive even in regions where that fruit is grown?" The concentrate is going to be the same price everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Because concentrates can be stored easily without bacterial growth and degradation. Fresh juices are very diluted and any trace of yeast or any other form of life can easily grow and degrade the product. So if you think to multi year storage the cheaper way is to concentrate the product and dilute it on request.